# Couldn't retrieve data using Loki's query endpoint, but can - using query_range

Tags: grafana-loki

In the query endpoint, I'm using a basic query like query `{log="error"}`, and I've verified that the time range is correctly specified. However, the result is empty. When using the query_range endpoint with the same query, I can retrieve the expected data within the specified time range

Example of result for query [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egKl5.png)
Example of result for query_range [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJR7O.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find exact description of how `/loki/api/v1/query` endpoint behaves when supplied with stream selector, but I'll guess that it's similar to Prometheus' staleness concept, and will return values for the last 5 minutes.

`/loki/api/v1/query_range` on the other hand if not supplied with explicit time range, like in your example, will return last hour of logs. See the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/reference/api/#query-loki-over-a-range-of-time) (emphasis mine):

> - `start`: The start time for the query as a nanosecond Unix epoch or another supported format. **Defaults to one hour ago**. Loki returns results with timestamp greater or equal to this value.
> - `end`: The end time for the query as a nanosecond Unix epoch or another supported format. **Defaults to now**. Loki returns results with timestamp lower than this value.

So explanation of this misalignment is probably simple difference in default time ranges for these two endpoints.

In general, if you intend to retentive full log from Loki's API, and not some aggregated values, you will be using `/loki/api/v1/query_range`, so this should not be an issue.